# TortoiseHg web server says it's stopped even though it's still running

Tags: webserver, tortoisehg

When I right click on my Hg folder and choose **TortoiseHg** > **Web Server**, I can start the web server on port 7999 without a problem.  I then shut that dialog box.  If I go and run `netstat -a -o` from a command prompt, I can see that an instance of `thgw.exe` is running and listening on port 7999 (even after closing the dialog box).  It's ironic that in Task Manager the `thgw.exe` process is called "TortoiseHg GUI tools for Mercurial SCM" even though there's no GUI running.

### Problem

If I open that dialog box again via **TortoiseHg** > **WebServer**, it reports that the status is "stopped", and the **Start** button is enabled.  This is incorrect because the port is still listening.  If I click the start button I get this message in the log as I'd expected:

> abort: cannot start server at ':7999': Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

### Questions

1. So why does TortoiseHg not realize that an existing `thgw.exe` is running on the port?
2. Is there a better way besides netstat and task manager to check if TortoiseHg is listening on a web port?  And also learn which port is representing which  folder?
3. I can't stop the web server so how are you supposed to gracefully shutdown a TortoiseHg web server without killing it from Task Manager? That seems like a scary thing to do to my production source control system!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the **Close** button of the **Serve** window is clicked, the window does not actually close, but minimize itself into the notification area. See the globe icon in the screenshot below:

[image: Serve window icon in the notification area]

If you click the icon, the original **Serve** window appears, where the **Start** button is actually disabled, and **Stop** enabled. You can stop the server from there.

This behavior was tested on TortoiseHg 2.4, Windows 7.

The only problem I see here is that the original window is not opened when you choose the appropriate menu item.

See also [issue 1845](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/1845) on the TortoiseHg bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks so much @Helgi, that answered my question!  Now that I see my icons in the tray I'm tracking down a new issue which is that some of my services seem to be started by different users and so they're not all showing up in my tray.  Obviously I need to come up with a best practice on what account I should be using but that's a separate issue.